# React: Execute some check before render

Tags: reactjs, rendering

Are there the ways how implement this idea:

I wanna do some check before render. If check is true than render. But if check is false, than firstly i need to do `setState`, and only after render.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe inside `componentDidMount() {}`?

Comment: `render() {}` is not the place for setState, you should handle your state in component lifecycle methods : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

Comment: That s why i have asked this question. My crome give me mistake about using `setState` in render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `componentWillMount()` is literally what you are after but putting it in the `constructor()` might be a better place for it.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    if (theCheck() === false) {
      this.state = {
        // ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is super ? And why we use just **state**, not **setState** ?

Comment: `super()` calls the original constructor function from the class you extended. In this case it would call the constructor from `React.Component`. `setState()` is a way to tell React that it needs to re-render the component because it’s state has changed. If you were to just update `this.state` it wouldn’t detect any difference. Using `this.state` in the constructor is valid because the component has not been rendered yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering it first, then do the check and change the state when it is already rendered by using `componentDidMount()`. Don't worry, it will be that fast that your eyes won't see it coming. The code will looks like this:

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (CHECK HERE) {
       this.setState({state : stateValue})
     }
   }
 }
```